# Average of rows with different column values

Tags: sql

2 tables

- Product(maker, model)
- PC(model, ..., price)

`model` is a foreign key between `Product` and `PC`

I need to select all rows in `Product` that have the same `maker` and average their `price`.

Therefore with these tables:

```
Product       PC
-------       -------
A    1        1    60
A    2        2    80
B    3        3    110
B    4        4    140
```

I should get:

```
maker      avg(price)
---------------------
A          70
B          125
```

I have tried this, but have no idea how to combine the rows and average just those that get combined. This displays the average across the entire `PC` table for all `maker`.

```
select 
    Product.maker, Product.model, avg(PC.price) 
from 
    Product, PC 
group by 
    Product.maker, Product.model 
order by 
    maker asc;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: You know as a student I've realized they teach us the most inefficient ways first. Thank you for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the old legacy implicit join syntax any more. Use explicit joins

```
select Product.maker, avg(PC.price) 
from Product
left join PC on PC.model = Product.model
group by Product.maker
order by Product.maker asc
```